# how to pass selected item to axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to pass the selected item in the dropdown menu to axios to get data.i need to pass item not id to api.

```
<label>City</label> 
<select  @change="getArea()"  v-model="key"  >
  <option :value='0'>Select City</option>
    <option v-for='data in cityList' :value='data.id'>{{ data.city }} 
  </option>
</select>

<script>
var self =this;
axios.get('http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city/'+this.key) //i want to pass selected item(text) to api.
  .then(function(res) {
    self.areaList = res.data;
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log('Error:',error);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**GET METHOD:**

```
function getArea(e) {
  let selectedVal = this.value;

  axios
    .get("http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city", {
      params: {
        city_id: 12345
      }
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      self.areaList = res.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

**POST METHOD:**

function getArea(e) {
      let selectedVal = this.value;

```
  axios
    .post("http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city", 
      {
        city_id: 12345
      })
    .then(function(res) {
      self.areaList = res.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: bro what is city_id??

Comment: city_id is the query param name in get request. If you directly want to make request to endpoint like "http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city/1".  Try concatinating url before passing it to axios.

Comment: i need to pass "city name" like "Banglore" not its id.

Comment: In your option.  <option v-for='data in cityList' :value='data.id'>{{ data.city }}</option> . You are taking data.id in value. change it to data.city for that.